# High Charts show series maximums below chart

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, highcharts

How do I display below a Column chart the series maximums in an HTML table?  Does HighCharts have an option for this or am I supposed to just use my model?

the backing bean is return JSON

**EDIT**
while not a jsf "problem", jsf could be a solution.  I'm using JSF2 and I'm passing JSON data model to a .xhtml.  Highhchart displays the data in a column form, but I also want to display the series data in a table below like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/

```
Highcharts.drawTable = function() {
```

However I need the html table inverted so that the months are across the top of the table. And the table columns should align with the chart (jan data right below and in alignment with the january highchart column)  Should I be redundant and pass both JSON model and non-JSON model and then use an JSF datatable to display values?  Or is the highchart method in the jsfiddle the better way?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed
You could get the maximum of each series (calculated in JS) and show it in an HTML table.

Comment: yes, but I believe this is the other way around.  I think that demo is extracting the data from a table to produce the graph.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you would like to display min/max value from serie, you can use getExtremes() function

http://jsfiddle.net/LeZtV/1/

```
chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMin
chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax
```

Comment: I realized my question wasn't worded quite like it should.  see my edit above. I'm looking for a table of the series values like the jsfiddle in my Q, except transpose the X->Y axis.